# Sitecore Remove Button

Tags: sitecore

I have a "Slide Show" control and I'd like to remove the first "X" button in the tool bar of the control. I have checked .ascx and .ascx.cs file to see if there is any related code, but nothing.

I think these buttons are from Core DB and I don't know where I can remove or hide this "X" button in Sitecore.

Could you help me, please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `Slide Show` sublayout in your Sitecore tree.

Scroll to `Editor Options` section and remove `Delete` from the `Page Editor Buttons` field.

[image]